# How to speak faster?

Tags: pronunciation

I learn the English language. I think I speak not so bad, but I have some problems with sentences like "**Is the** style and tone of the letter informal?". The problem is that I can't say "the" fast. My tongue just can't move so fast after the word "is".

Do you have any tips for me how to do it faster?

Comment: Don't work so hard to pronounce "the". When speaking quickly you can soften the "th" - and ignore the "d" on "and". Something like: "Is za style an' tone of the letter informal?" You should be easily understood.

Comment: But accent... I'm not really confident that I'll do that right. Where to find some audio which will show me how to do what you suggested me right?

Comment: Here's an idea: Ask a native to say the sentence quickly, and watch their mouth move as you listen. I used to work with a man who was born deaf.  His mother had insisted that he learn to speak - rather than using sign language. When he was unsure of pronunciation, he would ask me to say the word while he watched, in order to correct himself.

Comment: If I say that sentence fast, it sounds kinda like: _Izza style and tone of the letter informal?_

Comment: What is the necessity for speaking fast? When learning a language, or where a strong accent is an issue, it is better to speak slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, isolate the problem: in this sentence you must pronounce *the* after *is* and *of*. Despite the spelling, both words end in voiced consonants. If speakers of your native language generally devoice final consonants, then practice this in isolation.

Now practice getting from the *z* and *v* sounds to the voiced *th*:

> *izth*, *ovth*

Your tongue doesn't have far to go, but it must extend between the teeth so you can make the sound.

Finally, add the unstressed schwa vowel and pronounce as if these combinations were single words:

> *izthe*, *ovthe*

Concentrate on getting the tongue back quickly. Think of a lizard or snake. It may help to practice in front of a mirror.

Comment: when I say "izthe" z sounds the same as th?

Comment: Absolutely not! The point of the exercise is to make each sound properly but to move from a z to a voiced th very quickly.